# Copy values from datagidview to another datagidview on different form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a main form (FormXYZ) with a DataGridView which includes XYZ coordinates and names and descriptions of points. I am using a MenuStrip to call events using the selected points in the DGV.

When I call the event it will open a new form (Form4) with the relevant parameters for the function. I want to include a new DGV on this new form, which includes all of the points on the base DGV.

Below is the code I have so far which has been adapted from other posts I found on the subject. It seems to run without errors, but the new DGV does not show any data. This code describes how it will create the columns, based on the base DGV. I do not need this, as my DGVs will all contain the same columns, but I have left it in at this stage, until I can get some data transferred.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Public Class FormTranslate 
  Private Sub FormTranslate_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sourceGrid As DataGridView = FormXYZ.DataGridView1
    Dim targetGrid As DataGridView = Me.DGV1

    '----------
    'Copy all rows and cells.
    Dim targetRows = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)

    For Each sourceRow As DataGridViewRow In sourceGrid.Rows
        If (Not sourceRow.IsNewRow) Then
            Dim targetRow = CType(sourceRow.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In sourceRow.Cells
                targetRow.Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Value = cell.Value
            Next
            targetRows.Add(targetRow)
        End If
    Next

    'Clear target columns and then clone all source columns.
    targetGrid.Columns.Clear()

    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In sourceGrid.Columns
        targetGrid.Columns.Add(CType(column.Clone(), DataGridViewColumn))
    Next

    'It's recommended to use the AddRange method (if available)
    'when adding multiple items to a collection.
    targetGrid.Rows.AddRange(targetRows.ToArray())
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If both grids are going to show the same info, you should pass the datasource to the other form.  You should also start using explicit form instances

Comment: The data source for the base DGV is from CSV file and will be edited depending on the functions called. So the base DGV will be the data source which need to be transferred.

Comment: No, a `DataSource` would be the list or datatable which holds the data.  Apparently you are poking the data into DGV cells?  Dont do that